# How can we call matter to exist in wave form?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality, matter

Matter behaves as "waves and particles". But if we say that the object is a wave it means it is present everewhere at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The wave-particle duality principle does not speak so much as to the ontological essence of quantum particles in themselves as much as it does to the way we are able to understand the laws that govern them. For example, when we say that the electron is a wave, we are really only saying that the probability of locating the electron in any given region of space is through calculating a probability given by a complex-valued density function that is essentially a travelling wave, not that the electron is itself a wave travelling through space. When we observe quantum systems as sometimes exhibiting wave like properties and sometimes exhibting particulate behavior, we are really highlighting or the role of observation in some particular experiment. Observation "collapses" the probability density or wave function to some specific value consistent with the uncertainty principle, which localizes the quantum particle an makes us think of it like it were a particle. The point is that neither description is perfectly able to give us an intuitive picture of what is really going on at the quantum level. One must be careful to remember that quanta cannot be understood mentally as mechanical point particle or waves in the classical sense. This is why Feynmann was right when he said something along the lines of no one understands quantum mechanics, if he thinks he does then he has misunderstood it.

Comment: One way of illustrating just how strange and unintuitive quantum mechanics is can be understood from the following: The wave function is such that the electron has a high probability of being found at the Bohr radius of a hydrogen atom, however, an electron in a hydrogen atom in the andromeda galaxy also has a small but non-zero probability of being found in your next sandwich, or perhaps even of being in both locations at once!

Comment: So an object is not a wave . Only its probability amplitude is a wave. But when we say probability of finding "it" in a certain region in space the  "it" indicates to a point particle. Because a particle is the only thing about whose position we can talk

Comment: @ Chess Man. Not so, for example, one may speak of the position of a wave packet for example. Even extended objects like which we are familiar in everyday life are not precisely located at one point unless we are speaking of their center of mass. Experimental data allows for the calculation of a "form factor", however, and this data does indicate that the electron scatters as if it has no spatial extension at all, i.e. a true point particle. However, how does a point particle behave as electrons do in the slit experiment, or "buckyballs" for that matter?

Comment: The duality principle is useful, but difficult to make any sense of.

Comment: you wrote: "*an electron in a hydrogen atom in the andromeda galaxy also has a small but non-zero probability of being found in your next sandwich*" this just shows that, *pace* Kolmogorov, Cournot was right and sufficiently small probabilities are impossible events , see http://glennshafer.com/assets/downloads/disappear.pdf.

Comment: @hyportnex. "Never" and "impossible" are not quite the same things. One a matter of practice, one a matter of principle.

Comment: Bernoulli: Ars Conjectandi (1713). "Something is morally certain if its probability is so close to certainty that the shortfall is imperceptible. Something is morally impossible if its probability is no more than the amount by which moral certainty falls short of complete certainty."

Comment: @hyportnex. Excellent quote; knower of the arcane you are, lol.  However, there is just no a priori reason why a thousand monkeys couldn't eventually write one of Montaigne's essays if they were given enough time to bang away at random. But I have already morally transgressed? After all, it is true that I don't believe the universe will witness such a possibility.  The thing is not so much about what we believe as what  exists in a realm of possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think of  "a wave in what?". An electron is a wave in the electromagnetic quantum field. Just like a quark is a wave in the quark field and a gluon is a wave in the gluon field. Now think of a pebble dropped into a pond of water. Right where the pebble is dropped there will be a collection of waves that diminish very rapidly as you move away from that spot. It's the same thing in the quantum world. Right where the electron is located the waves are bigger and they diminish very rapidly but never to zero as you move away from that point. So don't just think of a particle as a wave sitting all by itself. Think of it as a wave in the associated quantum field.

Comment: "An electron is a wave in the electromagnetic quantum field". I... do not think this is correct.  In QFT, an electron is an excitation of the *electron* field, not the EM field.  And as to "You have to think of "a wave in what?"", I think that's exactly what you *don't* want to do with quantum particles. The "waviness" of the electron is not some kind of actual "wiggly-ness" in some kind of medium. Instead, it's that in experiments, one can get "wave-like outcomes" like double-slit patterns, etc.

Comment: Well i am a beginner in quantum mechanics and i have started to think of matter and light fundamentally. I don't know about quantun fields but As far as i think, an electron is completely a particle and its probability amplitude of finding it at a particular region is wave . Here the probability oscillates. Correct me if i am wrong somewhere

Comment: @Chess Man. Check out the Stern Gerlach experiment for some weirdness that gets right at the heart of the quantum subject.

Comment: @march you wrote: "*The "waviness" of the electron is not some kind of actual "wiggly-ness" in some kind of medium. Instead, it's that in experiments, one can get "wave-like outcomes" like double-slit patterns, etc.*" How is the 1st sentence is the "instead" of the 2nd one? What experiment can you devise that the wave-like results of  diffraction experiments deny the existence of said wiggly-ness in a medium? The wiggly-ness itself is an interpretation of the resulting interference.

Comment: @march for your second point, you only have to look at the iron filings around a bar magnet experiment to see that the field exists as some sort of medium that we just can't define right now. The virtual particles that you see in that experiment are merely the remnants of the actual particles in all of their wiggly-ness.